# Creating table using C# vs using Javascript/jQuery + Json

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

This may look like an opinion-based question but the reason I am asking this is to come up with an explanation on why I should use the other versus the other.

Scenario:
I am a new intern in this company where they have lots of ASP.NET MVC projects and one thing I noticed is that they are building a large row of tables using `c# foreach loop` like so:

```
@foreach(var i in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td>@i.Name</td>
      <td>@i.Amount</td>
      <td>@i.SomethingElse</td>
   </tr>
}
```

And I made a comment to my co-intern that it looks "stupid" and it makes the server do unnecessary workloads that can be done with javascript (so the workload is passed on to the client computer instead).

Then I didn't notice that the company developer was behind us and told me to prepare a list of reason how I can improve it and why I think that their "way" is stupid.

I am somehow new to programming and do not really know the ins and out of things but I know something is wrong with such practice (or not?). Can anyone give me a solid argument or explanation why I should pick the other over the other one?

Comment: This question is going to start a war of opinions on here !  Personally, my company has moved towards web services, and using Angular for displaying tables of data.  It just leaves simple, clean, maintainable, fast code.  For example, here's my webpage showing how I'd display some Northwind data using Angular:  http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.7.htm

Comment: *"I am somehow new to programming and do not really know the ins and out of things but I know something is wrong with such format."*, *"I made a comment to my co-intern that it looks "stupid" and it makes the server do unnecessary workloads"* Didn't you just answer your own question? Unless the content gets refreshed periodically (ajax, signalR, etc.) and there already is some kind of generation happening client-side, I'd leave the "load" (which I doubt is very high) on the server.

Comment: @MikeGledhill Yes that's what I thought so too. But I have to choose a side and I chose to stand with what I have said instead of just apologizing. Although I did apologize for the "words" I used in my comment but I still think client side processing is better.. I just don't exactly know how to convey my point.

Comment: BTW: I think this really is a good dev as he offers you the chance to discuss that topic based on facts and while doing that gives you the chance to learn something.

Comment: The "workload" is about the same. You either have to create a JSON-string from your Model or you create the Html from your Model. IMO it's way more userfriendly creating it directly with razor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"There is nothing wrong with this". That is the first thing I can confirm with you.

Even though I recommend you to read more about MVC, but in short, it doesn't increase the workload for server.

With MVC, there are 2 ways (as I know) to display data.

1. Traditional way like your company. Loading every data to a Model, and using View to display Model. This is how MVC design pattern work.
2. Return all bunch of datas to an interchange format (json, xml, but mostly is json), using Java-script to display those data.

Since I said there is nothing wrong, there will be pros and cons, and Method_1's pros is Method_2's cons: *(in my opinion, will update more after research on other pros and cons)*

**Pros:**

- With method 1, it will be easier to control with Razor syntax / C# syntax.
- Correct format of MVC.
- If using Method_2, you may need to copy-paste a lots of JavaScript if you have similar pages on same projects

**Cons:**

- it will be complicated when you are required to load more than one Model in a View.
- Does not apply if you has multiple Front-end.